# Ошибки в коде на python 3.8.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, бот

пытаюсь сделать бота для телеграм на python, объясните на примере моего кода, как после вывода "Правильно" из первой функции перейти ко второй, у меня выводит ошибку

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

```
x=0

if x == 0:
  @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
  def send_text(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '1)правильно   2)неправильно')
    if message.text=='1':
     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'правильно')
     x += 1
    elif message.text=='2':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'неправильно')
    elif message.text!='1' or '2':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'введите 1 или 2')



if x == 1:
  @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
  def send_text(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '1)правильно   2)неправильно')
    if message.text=='1':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'правильно')
      x += 1
    elif message.text=='2':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'неправильно')
    elif message.text!='1' or '2':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'введите 1 или 2')
```

Comment: добавьте свой код не в виде картинки, а в виде текста, так удобней будет использовать тем, кто будет отвечать. Ссылка "Править" под вопросом

Comment: Заодно объясните о каких ошибках речь и приведите заголовок в соответствие самому вопросу.

Comment: Не вносите изменения в вопрос, когда дан ответ и смысл вопроса меняется кардинально. Теперь кто столкнется с  такой же проблемой и будет искать ответ не сможет найти его. Задан вопрос - получен ответ. Точка

Comment: Не исправляйте вопрос, тем более если вы уже получили на него ответ. Лучше задайте новый вопрос. `global x` надо писать *сразу под заголовком функции*, иначе у вас в других ветках `x` будет по-прежнему локальной переменной. Кроме того, бот может функционировать в другом потоке, это всё заведомо неправильный шаблон работы с переменными то, как вы делаете.

Comment: Как сказать ["спасибо"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), [вопрос-ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour). Спасибо, за понимание

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Вы меняете переменную `x` внутри функции, а питон по умолчанию считает переменные, которые вы меняете в функции, локальными переменными этой функции. Нужно подсказать питону, что это глобальная переменная:

```
def send_text(message):
    global x
```

Но вообще глобальные переменные это не самый лучший стиль программирования, по возможности лучше как-то обходиться без них.